# "NameError - uninitialized constant" when running function from singleton model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

I'm getting "NameError - uninitialized constant Store::DirectedEdge" when I call the below statement from another controller.

```
Store.instance.add_purchase(1, 2)
```

Below is my singleton 'Store' model:

```
require 'singleton'

class Store 
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @database = DirectedEdge::Database.new(ENV['DIRECTED_EDGE_USERNAME'], ENV['DIRECTED_EDGE_PASSWORD'])
  end

  def add_purchase(user_id, product_id)
    item = DirectedEdge::Item.new(@database, "user#{user_id}")
    item.link_to("product#{product_id}", "purchase")
    item.save
  end

  ...

end
```

Anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: what is `DirectedEdge` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to require `DirectedEdge` like this `require 'directed_edge'`. Here is link for documentation [Directed Edge](http://developer.directededge.com/article/Getting_started_for_Ruby_developers) with example.